# Multiple attachments with paperclip, I can't figure it out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Creating this Support System RoR app.

I have this Ticket Model, and currently it does support having one attachment with paperclip and everything works great.

However, my app needs to have the ability to support at least up to 3 attachments per "Ticket".

I've searched, and haven't found any good solution on how to achieve this, any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to make a new model "Document" that belongs to Ticket and the Ticket model would have many documents:

1- Create the Document model/migration file.

```
add_attachment :documents, :doc
```

also you should add foreign key to documents table.

2- In your Ticket model add

```
has_many :documents
accepts_nested_attributes_for :documents
```

3- Add the following in Document model:

```
belongs_to :ticket
has_attached_file :doc
```

This way you could add as much documents as you want to each ticket.

**EDIT:**

For the views code. I haven't test the following code, but I would do the following:

In controller

```
(@ticket.documents.count .. MAX_DOCUMENTS).each do
    @ticket.build_document
end
```

And in the views:

```
<%-@ticket.documents.each_with_index do |document,i|-%> 
    <div class="field">
    <%- if document.new_record? -%>
        <input id="ticket_documents_attributes_<%=i.to_s%>_doc" name="ticket[documents_attributes][<%=i.to_s%>][doc]" type="file" />
    <%- else -%>
        <%= document.doc_file_name %>
        <%= link_to t(:remove), delete_document_ticket_path(id: document.id) %>
    <%- end -%>
    </div>
<%-end-%>
```

You would have to implement the delete function if you want.

Comment: I thought about that -- but ... how would I accomplish this on my view? ... How do i make available the ability to upload multiple files?

Comment: check out `https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form` gem, you can create dynamic field so you can upload multiple files.